# Blank line before return statement

Tags: php, phpstorm

How to add a new blank line before the return statement?
I wanna change my code style in PhpStorm.

Like there https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-337283

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | Code Style | PHP
- Blank Lines | Minimum Blank Lines | Before return statement

[image]